# Нужно посчитать количество улыбающихся смайликов в массиве без использования библиотек и т.д

Tags: python

```
countSmileys = [':)', ':)' ';(', ';}', ':-D']
def count_smileys(arr):
    if ')' and 'D' in arr:
        return len(')' and 'D')

print(count_smileys(countSmileys))
```

Задача такая: ***Посчитать улыбающиеся смайлики. Улыбающийся смайлик - это в котором есть символ ")" или "D", остальные не действительны***

Не могу понять логики, столько циклов уже переписал, все рано не получается посчитать, помогите

Comment: использовал метод count, но почему-то возвращает значения 0

Comment: Стоило бы привести примеры циклов, которые вы пробовали, чтобы вам подсказали, что не так. Как говорится, лучше научить рыбачить, чем дать рыбу.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов
countSmileys = [':)', ':)' ';(', ';}', ':-D']


def count_smileys(arr):

    if ')' and 'D' in arr:
        return len(')' and 'D')


print(count_smileys(countSmileys))

Comment: Ну а где тут цикл? `for smiley in arr: ...` и в нем проверяй `smiley` на соответствие нужным смайлам, к примеру `if smiley in [':)', ':D']: counter = counter + 1` и т.д.

Comment: @hoefling да я и с циклом for проверял, где-то тупил) Стоит больше вниманию уделить всем этим циклам, так и сделаю.

Comment: @VyacheslavBondarev У Вас гораздо больше ошибок. Я обновил свой ответ, почитайте, думаю, Вам будет интересно.

Comment: Можно красиво сделать лямбдой : `count_smileys = lambda arr: sum((')' in smile or 'D' in smile) for smile in arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверки на присутствие символов `)` или `D` можно делать с помощью оператора `in`.
Вернётся `True`, если символ присутствует в строке, иначе - `False`.

Для Вашего примера проверка будет выглядеть так: `if ')' in smile or 'D' in smile:`

В зависимости от этого результата следует инкрементировать счётчик, который впоследствии будет возвращён из функции.

***Код:***

```py
def count_good_smiles(smileys: list) -> int:
    i = 0
    for smile in smileys:
        if ')' in smile or 'D' in smile:
            i += 1

    return i


smileys = [':)', ':)', ';(', ';}', ':-D']
print(count_good_smiles(smileys))
```

*stdout:*

```html
3
```

---

**Возьмите на заметку!**

Ошибки в Вашем коде:

1. `[':)', ':)' ';(', ';}', ':-D']`. Приглядитесь, Вы пропустили запятую, но ошибки не возникло, так как неявно произошла конкатенация строк `:)` и `;(`
2. `')' and 'D' in smile`. Выполняется только 2-ая проверка. Строка `)` всегда возвращает логическое `True` и никак не связана с оператором `in`
3. У вас нет цикла. Условие выше проверяет не каждый конкретный смайлик, а весь массив в целом на нахождение в нём элемента `D`
4. `return len(')' and 'D')`. Вернётся длина 2-ой строки (`D`, то есть `1`). Это никак не связано с Вашей задачей

Также следует придерживаться `PEP-8`, а именно: оставлять 2 пустые строки перед и после объявления функции.

Answer (score 1):

```
len([s for p in ')D' for s in smileys if p in s])  # 3
```

Comment: Предлагаю `len([s for s in smileys if set(')D') & set(s)])` -  в вашем варианте смайлик `':-D)'` посчитается 2 раза.